# Will spring 4.1 support JSF 1.2?

Tags: spring, jsf, jsf-1.2

I would like to know if spring 4.1 supports JSF 1.2 version. Currently my application is using JSF 1.2 and spring 1.2.

I am upgrading to spring 4.1 so I would like to know if spring 4.1 supports JSF 1.2.

Comment: You upgraded Spring to its latest version (or at least you are about to upgrade). Why not upgrading JSF too instead of showing interest in the legacy JSF 1.2?

Comment: @Tiny Started upgrading. My Client was not interested to upgrade JSF so want to know if spring 4.1 supports or not

Comment: As for [this](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/WFK2-805?focusedCommentId=13025193&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-13025193) comment, it does not. "*Spring 3.2.x is still using JSF 1.2 but as of Spring 4, it requires JSF 2.*" I myself cannot confirm that comment. The Google search result basically leads to higher JSF versions usually JSF2.x when Google is told about Spring 4.x.

Comment: @Tiny: That comment is about *Spring WebFlow*, which is a subproject of Spring. Spring itself still supports JSF 1.2.

Comment: @sleske what you said is true I would like to know even spring 4.1 supports 1.1 jsf?

Answer (score 0):

in general Spring and JSF versions does not connected and Spring could not affect in JSF in theory, you should integrate Spring4 as well as old versions.

Comment: you mean to say we can integrate jsf 1.2 with spring 4?

Comment: "Spring and JSF versions does not connected": this is wrong. Spring has special code for integrating with JSF, which does depend on a specific version: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Spring 4.1 still supports JSF 1.2:

> 19. Integrating with other web frameworks
>
> [...]
>
> 19.3 JavaServer Faces 1.2

Source: Spring reference, [19. Integrating with other web frameworks](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/web-integration.html).

Note that this is only for basic support for JSF, namely the SpringBeanFacesELResolver (which allows a JSF page to reference spring beans as backing beans), and for FacesContextUtils.

If you want to use Spring WebFlow, the current version 2.4 requires JSF 2.0 (see [Spring WebFlow 2.4 - What's New](http://docs.spring.io/spring-webflow/docs/2.4.0.RELEASE/reference/html/whatsnew.html#whatsnew-swf-jsf20) ).

Comment: After your valuable information I started using JSF1.2 but I got stucked with errors this is the link which shows where I got stucked [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28342750/nullpointerexception-while-trying-to-load-application-context-in-jsf-1-2)