# NullPointerException while trying to load application context in JSF 1.2

Tags: spring, jsf, jsf-1.2

Null pointer exception is coming while trying to load application context while migrating to jsf 1.2.

Below is the stack trace

```
    [ERROR] [com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase] [] - #   {CustomerSearchBean.searchCustomers}: javax.faces.el.EvaluationException: 
     java.lang.NullPointerException
    javax.faces.FacesException: #{CustomerSearchBean.searchCustomers}: javax.faces.el.EvaluationException: java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:78)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.TailFilter.doFilter(TailFilter.java:26)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)

    ... 29 more
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.tms.cdqi.presentation.jsf.bean.customerprofile.CustomerSearchBean.searchCustomers(CustomerSearchBean.java:134)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at com.sun.faces.el.MethodBindingImpl.invoke(MethodBindingImpl.java:126)
```

Below is the faces-xml

```
 <managed-bean>
    <description>This bean is used for customer profile</description>
    <managed-bean-name>CustomerSearchBean</managed-bean-name>
    <managed-bean-class>com.tms.cdqi.presentation.jsf.bean.customerprofile.CustomerSearchBean</managed-bean-class>
    <managed-bean-scope>request</managed-bean-scope>
    <managed-property>
        <property-name>commandInvoker</property-name>
        <value>#{commandInvoker}</value>
    </managed-property>
    <managed-property>
        <property-name>applicationContextFactory</property-name>
        <value>#{cdqiApplicationContextFactory}</value>
    </managed-property>

</managed-bean>
```

Edit 1: 
        Below is the Application context xml

```
       <beans xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
  xsi:schemaLocation="
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

<bean id="cdqiApplicationContextFactory"
    class="com.tms.cdqi.framework.context.CDQIApplicationContextFactoryImpl" />
```

Edit 2 Code

```
    The application context  where null pointer is occurring

    CDQIApplicationContext context = this.getApplicationContextFactory()
            .getApplicationContext();
```

Comment: @tiny can you let me know your suggestion

Comment: Well, it looks like `this.getApplicationContextFactory()` is null. Try investigating this further. What does this method do?

Comment: @sleske it will call the managed bean and property value present in the faces-config file and then load the bean present in application context

Comment: Well, then figure out why it returns null. We cannot debug for you.

Comment: @sleske just want to know if you have any idea of  how jsf 1.2 works on managed beans.

Comment: Yes, I have, but that does not tell me why this method returns null. As I said, investigate why the method returns null, and edit that into your question, then maybe we'll see the problem.

Comment: @sleske a doubt when I use jsf 1.1 with delegatevariable resolver this.getApplicationContextFactory() is loading fine but when I changed to jsf 1.2 with SpringBeanFacesELResolver  elresolver  this.getApplicationContextFactory() is getting null is it anything because of version or something else